# How to manage bunch of routes from API and their component association with Nuxt router module

Tags: nuxt.js

Hello dear Nuxt/Vue/Node community,

I encounter some issues of load time and memory leak on my Nuxt.js application which seems to come from the routing part.

**Some context :**

I'm building an e-commerce website with an obvious need of SEO.
I'm using Laravel as backend which serve a Nuxt.js SSR through a RESTful API.

One of my API endpoint "/urls" gives all the urls of pages/products/menus/etc. of the application and on the Nuxt.js part I associate these urls with their relative components in the router.js (i'm using the "nuxt-community/router-module").

The Nuxt.js part is not in static mode and works in production as live SSR application (nuxt build/start).

**The issue :**

As it is, the load time of my first page is very slow (10sec+) as it loads all the urls from API and associate them with their relative component (based on each url pattern), plus it's very heavy for the server as it's loaded for each user of the application for the first page loaded...

Could you explain me the best way to deal with remote urls and Nuxt.js component ? Maybe there is some ways to use a global route middleware that could catch the request and associate the url with the right component on the fly or maybe there is a better way to do this...

Subsidiary question : Is it a problem for Nuxt.js to work with 20.000+ urls with the router ?

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 0):

You do not need server side rendering for that situation as you have a Laravel API. I suggest you to use Vue.js instead with which the solution of your problem is quite straightforward when you apply [lazy loading](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/lazy-loading.html).

Comment: Hi Billal and thanks for your comment.
I think i missed something in my context... i'm building an e-commerce application so the need of SEO is very important, so that is why i'm using the SSR mode and not the SPA one, and why i'm using Nuxt.js over Vue.js.